# Match SNORT IP alerts to specific URLs

Tags: ubuntu, ip, snort

I have SNORT running on an Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have alerts firing off but the alert logs come through as IP addresses. I have a list of websites the system has visited throughout the day.

Is there a way of matching the URLs to the alerts?

One way I have thought is doing a domain -> IP translation and then matching the IP and time of visit with the alert log but is there a more accurate way?

Comment: I'd consider running a passive dns collector to help correlate these alerts. E.g https://github.com/gamelinux/passivedns